# How to display many images through ListAdpter?

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

I have an android activity that reads some items from the web server, everything is alright except the image.
 
I've done the same with only one item and it worked, but I can't think of anyway to read many items and set their value to imageView.

Is there anyway that allows me to set the image value to the listAdapter after ending them by hashmap?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

### Here is the code:

```
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(GetAllRecipesActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category", R_category));
        Log.d("R_category: ", R_category);
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);
        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_table);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_SCB_ID);
                    String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    name= name.substring(1, name.length());
                    name="http://studentcookbook.comoj.com/android_connect"+name;

                    Log.d("NAME OF THE URL!",name);

                 // here i'm starting to set the image value it's all good here 
                    downloadBitma =downloadBitmap(name);
                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, Object> map=new HashMap<String, Object>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                    map.put(TAG_SCB_ID, id);

                    map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);

                    map.put(TAG_NAME, downloadBitma);
                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {

                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AddRecipeActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Buffer Error", " Image is not passing to hashmap");
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                // here i'm trying to set the image to imageView but it didn't work
//                  final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.GetAllmg); 
//                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {  
//                    @Override  
//                      public void run() {  
//                  imageView.setImageBitmap(downloadBitma);        }  
//                     });  
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(GetAllRecipesActivity.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_recipe, new String[] { TAG_SCB_ID,TAG_TITLE},
                        new int[] { R.id.GetAllscbid, R.id.GetAllTitle });
                // updating listview
                Toast.makeText(GetAllRecipesActivity.this, "onPostExecute",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }
// method for downloading images 
    private Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) throws IOException {  
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(url.toString());  
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);  

        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();  
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();  
        if (statusCode == 200) {  
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();  
            byte[] bytes = EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity);  

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0,  
                    bytes.length);  
            return bitmap;  
        } else {  
            throw new IOException("Download failed, HTTP response code "  
                    + statusCode + " - " + statusLine.getReasonPhrase());  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: yes, image loaders ... it is easy to google them, if you try.

Comment: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.` but, yeah, you could give this one a try ...

Answer (score -1):

I recommend [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

Comment: Could you guide me to it or just give me a hint where to start? As the package seems to be too much for what I asked for